# Callback Editable PHP Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have created a table where I can edit inside `td` and it works very well. I edited the name of product and it changed successfully just on my webpage, BUT it is not updating into Database.

My database would be like this:

[image]

Here is the code for editing inside `td`.

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM productList");
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    <td> <span class="edit" id="'.$row['ID'].'"> '.$row['name'].' </span> </td>
}
```

For editable, I have to use AJAX to call the value back. Something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
    $('.edit').editable();     
    $(document).on('click','.editable-submit',function(){
        var x = $(this).closest('td').children('span').attr('id');
        var y = $('.input-sm').val();
        var z = $(this).closest('td').children('span');
        $.ajax({
            url: "edit.php?id="+x+"&data="+y,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(s){
                if(s == 'status'){
                $(z).html(y);}
                if(s == 'error') {
                alert('Error Processing your Request!');}
            },
            error: function(e){
                alert('Error Processing your Request!!');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

After AJAX, I have to call url to `edit.php`. The code for `edit.php` is below:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','database_name');
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

if($_GET['id'] and $_GET['name'])
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    if ($mysqli->query("UPDATE productList SET name='$name' WHERE ID='$id'"));
    $mysqli->close();
    echo 'success';
}
```

I have tried to update manually in phpmyadmin, it works very well there. But not here. It should be working right now. Am I missing something?

Comment: Check if mysqli throws an error when you try to update the row.

Comment: Can you tell me how to throw as I am using AJAX, I'm too new with AJAX. I have tried throws an error in edit.php but it doesn't show any errors :/

Answer (score 0):

Need to update your code like below. And you can directly call the `edit.php?id=..&name=..` to debug if the file is ok.

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "edit.php?id="+x+"&name="+y,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(s){
                alert(s) ;
                if(s == 'status'){
                   $(z).html(y);
                }                    
            },
            error: function(e){
                alert(e.status);
            }
        });
```

PHP:

```
if($_GET['id'] && $_GET['name']) // this is not SQL! so and will not work!
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    if ($result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE productList SET name='".$name."' WHERE ID='". $id."'")){

       $mysqli->close(); 
       echo 'success';
    }else{
        echo mysqli->error;
    }


}
```

[READ Some MYSQLI DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: Hello thank you for the hints, but there appears some errors like `Error Processing Your Request!!` I couldn't get it.

Comment: `$.ajax({url: "edit-productList.php?id="+x+"&data="+y,type: 'GET'` I am confirming that the page is correct. but for `ID` and `Data` should be like that in AJAX right? @Riad

Comment: you are using  `$_GET['name']` but why passing &data=.. ? see the updated answer